# White Screen when making a POST request using Guzzle PHP

Tags: php, post, nginx, guzzle, wsod

I have a POST API which returns to me a huge data response. When I try to make the POST request a white screen error is thrown without any information.

However, when I reduce the amount of data to be returned the response is as expected.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 server, PHP 5.6 and Nginx 1.9.

My execution time, post_max_time, etc are all set to high value.

Comment: PHP errors are all on.

Comment: @MalabyaTewari Check the web server's logs, then.